# Save C# VLC screenshot

Tags: c#, vlc

I have been through multiple libraries and have been browsing and researching for the whole day and every single time the library isn't finished, there is no documentation or it doesn't work. How can I open a video file within a C# app and dump a random screenshot?

Comment: Hope this doesn't get closed, writing up an actual answer for this.

Comment: I have no idea why this is closed. The OP is asking how to take a screenshot of a video with C#. Not asking for a tool/library.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure how you can do this with VLC Player, but you can use ffmpeg:

Download ffpmeg from here: http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html

If you're using windows download the `static` version from the windows builds: http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/

This gives you a stand-alone .exe file rather than a whole heap of files.

---

### Running ffmpeg manually

Using it without C# you can open up a console window and run the command like so:

`ffmpeg -i "AngularJS - Part 1 - Hello Angular.mp4" -ss 00:02:25.435 -f image2 -vframes 1 screenshot.jpg`

The `00:02:25.435` part is actually the long time code, formatted like:

hours : minutes : seconds . frame percentage

If you want the frame at 5 seconds you would pass in: `00:00:05.000`

While if you wanted 2 minutes, 38 seconds, 12th frame. You would do `00:02:38.480`

To calculate the frame percentage just do `frame / frame rate` i.e `12 / 25` which is 0.48

To generate a screen grab.

[image]

---

### Running ffmpeg in C-Sharp

Now if you want to do this in a an application you can do:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    var startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    {
        WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
        WorkingDirectory = "C:/Users/Phillip/Desktop/ffpmeg sample/",
        FileName = "cmd.exe",
        Arguments = "/C ffmpeg -i \"AngularJS - Part 1 - Hello Angular.mp4\" -ss " +
                    "00:02:25.435 -f image2 -vframes 1 \"screenshot-from-app.jpg\""
    };
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    process.Start();

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

So we create a new process, to run a command, which happens to be the same command as we manually ran, except we prefix with `/C` which causes it to run the command and then terminate the console window after.

You can get more info about getting screen grabs from the ffmpeg website:

http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video

http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki

Comment: Thanks! How can I grab a random frame from the video?

Comment: If you know the duration of the video you can generate a random timecode to pass in. You can get metadata of a video with ffmpeg with `ffmpeg -i "video file" -f ffmetadata metadata.txt`, parse it, then get the duration.

Comment: Can I ask for this is for? You may be able to get away with just asking for the screenshot at 1 minute, if its a web app thing you could allow the user to pick the frame in HTML5.

Comment: I want this to execute automatically upon the finished download of a file, some videos will be shorter than 1 minutes so the 1 minute approach isn't good in this case.

Comment: Then I suggest getting the meta data, parse the duration out, and generate a random timecode.